# input string was not in the correct format error

Tags: c#, .net

I have no idea why this error is occurring can anyone tell me

```
 long? Max = row["MAX"].ToString() != null || row["MAX"].ToString() != "" ? long.Parse(row["MAX"].ToString()) : (long?)null;
```

Comment: What is the value of `row["MAX"]`? Step through your code, use your debugger!

Comment: Try to log row["MAX"]. You'll find it's not a valid number.

Comment: Your `row["MAX"]` does not contain a `long` value.

Comment: Because row["MAX"] can't be parsed to a long?

Comment: i did use the debugger and row["MAX"]=""

Comment: @Sora then you have the answer because "" definitely is not a valid number.

Comment: @Adriano but in my case if row["MAX"]="" it should return null right ?

Comment: @Sora no, it's an empty string, not a null string. Change your check to String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["MAX"]) because row["MAX"].ToString() will never be null (if row["MAX"] is null then it'll throw a NullReferenceException when you try to invoke ToString()).

Comment: what is the value of row["MAX"] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to check if `row["MAX"]` is `null` then you should change that check to:

```
row["MAX"] != null
```

This because return value of `ToString()` is never `null` but it'll throw a `NullReferenceException` if you invoke it on a `null` object (then `row["MAX"].ToString()` will fail for `null` objects).

In your case it's not `null` but it's an empty string, you *may* change to this:

```
long? Max = (row["MAX"] != null && row["MAX"].ToString() != "") 
    ? long.Parse(row["MAX"].ToString()) : (long?)null;
```

But as you can see it's not really readable, I would change (skipping any other validation) to:

```
long? Max = null;
if (row["MAX"] != null && row["MAX"].ToString() != "")
    Max = Long.Parse(row["MAX"].ToString());
```

**EDIT** as pointed out in [Jota WA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20399072/1207195) (which I consider right) if your row `object` comes from a database (actually we don't know its type so we can just guess and assume it's kind of dictionary of `object`) you may have `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`. In this case `row["MAX"] != null` is `false` but this condition is catched by 2nd check `row["MAX"].ToString() != ""`. That said if this is your case and you're sure your *dictionary* doesn't contain any *real* `null` value you may make it simpler:

```
if (row["MAX"].ToString() != "")
```

Or even:

```
if (row["MAX"] != DBValue.Null)
```

I suppose you may need to *add* validation then you should use `TryParse` like this:

```
// Here you may handle row["MAX"] == null case, if it may happen
string MaxText = row["MAX"].ToString();

long? Max = null;
if (MaxText  != "")
{
    long value;
    if (long.TryParse(MaxText, out value))
    {
        // You may add more validation here, for example
        // to check value's range
        Max = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for both `Empty String` and `null`.

while checking for `null` you can not invoke `ToString()` as if the value is `null` it `throws` `NullReferenceException`.

Try This:

```
long? Max = (row["MAX"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["MAX"].ToString()))? long.Parse(row["MAX"].ToString()) : (long?)null;
```

Comment: @Downvoter : would be glad if you could improve this.

Comment: Well because **before edit** it was **same answer of Dhaval** and it was **wrong for the same reasons**. **Now it's right** (even is 2nd check for null after ToString() is redundant because it can't be) but it has been said elsewhere too. That said now it works, not +1 but revert -1 (if you edit again after 5 minutes because of lock)

Comment: @Adriano: yes , Thanks for your valuable point, edited to remove duplicate checks. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Here it is:

```
long? val;
long parsedVal;
if (long.TryParse(row["MAX"].ToString(), out parsedVal))
{
   val = null;
}
else
{
   val = parsedVal;
}
```

Comment: Does it even compile (not just for missing parenthesis...)

Comment: It should compile now, writing in stackoverflow textarea didn't check compilation and casting. Anyway, the hints were correct. I think @Adriano ha mangiato acido stamattina eh...

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're getting an error because of the `row["MAX"].ToString() != null`.
If row["MAX"] is null then the ToString() method will throw an exception.Change it to only row["MAX"] != null (if is a null value from a DB the use DBNull.Value instead).

P.S: you don't need to use (long?)null because the type "long?" already supports null.

Comment: `If row["MAX"] is null then the ToString() method will throw an exception` Nope.

Comment: @DGibbs yes, it'll do.

Comment: @Adriano Have you tried calling `.ToString()` on row with a null reference? You get `""`. At least I just did when I tested it.

Comment: @DGibbs what's type of your row? Here we can't see but for sure it's not a value type (otherwise no need to parse it) then **it can be null** then it'll throw. Best assumption is...it's a generic "object".

Comment: I used a `DataRow`, since it's a good assumption that op is probably using this too. With column typeof string and int. Meh..

Comment: @DGibbs it's just our assumption (anyway Jota mentioned that too in his answer). Without more context he explained all in his answer (that's why my +1)