# Can you help me with an error I've been receiving: "input string was not in the correct format?"

Tags: c#

New to stackoverflow here! So if anyone also haves any tips on how to post a good question I would much appreciate that. Also new to c# which is what I am creating this program with.

The application takes two random integers and displays them to labels to where it will say: what is the value of (randomNumber1) + (randomNumber2) =? . The user is suppose to add the numbers together and input their answer to the Answer text box. But after debugging and running the program, I receive the error, "input string was not in the correct format" in the fifth line that says:

correctAnswer = Convert.ToInt32("" + labelNumber1.Text + labelNumber2.Text); .

code:

```
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int correctAnswer;
        correctAnswer = Convert.ToInt32("" + labelNumber1.Text + labelNumber2.Text);

        int userAnswer;
        userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(answerTextBox.Text);

        if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
        {
            correctAnswer = int.Parse(resultLabel.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your Answer is Incorrect");
            correctAnswer = int.Parse(resultLabel.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looking at the specification for [Convert.Int32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_) it says that you'll get that exception if `value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).`. You need to make sure that `labelNumber1.Text` and `labelNumber2.Text` is just digits or `-+` and nothing else.

Comment: What are the values of `labelNumber1.Text` and `labelNumber2.Text`? Both are empty or one or both is not a number. The same goes for `answerTextBox.Text`

Comment: [Here are some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to post a good question.

Comment: FYI you don't need the `""` when concatenating the two `Text` properties as they are already `string`.

Comment: I tried to re-title the question and remove the first sentence, it said there's already a question named so, which is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398965/input-string-was-not-in-the-correct-format-error 
first, go https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and see
Have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add two strings and treat them like numbers in the `Convert.ToInt32()` method. You have to parse them one at a time and then add them as integers, like this:

```
int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(labelNumber1.Text);
int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(labelNumber2.Text);
correctAnswer = number1 + number2;
```

I would also use exception handling to catch if there is any `FormatException` thrown, as the error you are giving shows the input being entered isn't a number, so it must have one or more non-numeric characters in it.

```
try {
    // TODO: Code
}
catch (FormatException er)
{
    lblError.Text =  "Error: You must enter in a number.";
}
```

Comment: Also I'm guessing they should be doing `resultLabel.Text = correctAnswer.ToString();`

Comment: I am still getting the "input string was not in the correct format" error specifically @ the line that says: int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(labelNumber1.Text);

Comment: @daydayday Then it's not a number. What are you typing in `labelNumber1.Text`? Either nothing at all (which isn't a number), or something else that isn't a number.

Comment: @daydayday Then that must mean the string entered in `labelNumber1` had one or more non-numeric characters in it. Put in a `try-catch` block to catch any number format or input mismatch exceptions.

Comment: @MaxVoisard, I agree that your solution will work, but we use `TryParse()` to have safe type casting. I believe `try{}catch` is not require here. `TryParse()` will solve OPs problem

Answer (score 1):

Data type of `labelNumber1.Text` and `labelNumber2.Text` is string. When you do `+` for two strings i.e `string + string` then it concatenate, but here you are trying to add two label texts so first convert each text into int and then add it.

```
int correctAnswer = int.MinValue;
if(int.TryParse(labelNumber1.Text, out int number1) && int.TryParse(labelNumber2.Text, out int number2))
   {
      correctAnswer = number1 + number2;
   }
```